# first-of-type and nth-of-type(1) are not working with dynamique div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem with first-of-type and nth-of-type(1) to hide the first element of a class.

In my script, user can add input text and he will have the choice to delate this inputs. the first item (which is the first element)won't be hidden, so without the link of delate.

The problem that when add first-of-type or nth-of-type(1), all links of delete are hidden. For the script every div item added is the first one, this is why the delete is hidden all time.

This is my script:

```js
$(function() {

  var max_fields = 10;
  var $wrapper   = $(".containerDim");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field");
  
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    const vals = $("> .item input[name^=poids]",$wrapper).map(function() { return +this.value }).get()
    const val = vals.length === 0 ? 0 : vals.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    
    if ($("> .item",$wrapper).length < max_fields && val < 300) {
      const $form_colis = $(".item").first().clone();
      $form_colis.find("input").val("");
      // $wrapper.append($form_colis); //add input box
      $('.item', $wrapper).last().after($form_colis);
      
    } else {
      var err_msg = 'Veuillez nous contacter!';
      //alert(err_msg);
      window.alert(err_msg);
    }
  });

  $wrapper.on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  })
});
```

```css
.delete:nth-of-type(1) {
  display:none;
}
.delete:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dimensions" class="row item">
    
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>Longueur(cm):</label>
    <input type="number"  min="0" name="longueurs[]" id="length"  value="<?php //echo $length;?>" required>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>Largeur(cm):</label>
    <input type="number"  min="0" name="largeurs[]" id="width" value="<?php //echo $width;?>" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>Hauteur(cm):</label>
    <input type="number"  min="0" name="hauteurs[]" id="height" value="<?php //echo $height;?>" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <label>Poids(Kg):</label>
    <input type="text"  min="0" name="poids[]" id="weight" value="<?php //echo $weight;?>"required>
  </div>  
  
  <!--div class="col-sm-1 "-->
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
  <!--/div-->
    
</div> <!-- row dimensions item -->
```

There is any solution to resolve that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: the jQuery you provided and the DOM selectors do not match with the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a wrapper `.containerDim` there are `.items` and only they can be used as a relevant *indexing* reference:

```css
.containerDim .item:nth-child(1) .delete {}
```

or

```css
.containerDim .item:first-of-type .delete {}
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  const max_fields = 10;
  const $wrapper = $(".containerDim");
  const add_button = $(".add_form_field");
  
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const vals = $(".item input[name^=poids]", $wrapper).map(function() {
      return +this.value
    }).get()
    
    const val = vals.length === 0 ? 0 : vals.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

    if ($(".item", $wrapper).length < max_fields && val < 300) {
      const $itemClone = $(".item", $wrapper).eq(0).clone();
      $("input", $itemClone).val("");
      $wrapper.append($itemClone); // use .append()
    } else {
      window.alert('Veuillez nous contacter!');
    }
  });

  $wrapper.on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.item').remove(); // use .closest() and go for a specific class!
  });
});
```

```css
.containerDim .item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.containerDim .item:nth-child(1) .delete{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerDim">
  <!-- Remove the ID id="dimensions"  you cannot have duplicated iDs -->
  <div class="row item">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>Longueur(cm):</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" name="longueurs[]" id="length" value="10" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>Largeur(cm):</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" name="largeurs[]" id="width" value="10" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>Hauteur(cm):</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" name="hauteurs[]" id="height" value="10" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <label>Poids(Kg):</label>
      <input type="text" min="0" name="poids[]" id="weight" value="1" required>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="add_form_field">ADD MORE</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```